# Bluetooth fix for Ubuntu 12.04, lenovo G580

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth

Bluetooth not working, it shows turned on but manager indicated Bluetooth disabled. Uninstalled default manager and installed Blueman. The same with Blueman, clicking on connect to devices gets response 'adapters not found'. I've found many more people with the same problem.

The fixes found in the archive don't work for me. I've tried a couple of things from the forum.

I'm not familiar with computer hardware or software but have been using Ubuntu cause it saves me money, it's fairly easy to use and it does not tax my mid-range lap. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what is output of `rfkill list all` once the bt is turned on?

Answer (score 0):

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```